# Is Digimon Universe: Appli Monsters Part of the Adventure Timeline?

Tags: digimon

The reason I ask is due to the fact that the series, Digimon Universe: Appli Monsters, is advertised as being set in the future of 2045 and the last moment in time (for now, at least) for the Digimon Adventure timeline is 2026, the infamous Epilogue at the end of Digimon Adventure 02. This would leave 19 years in between the Digimon Adventure 02 Epilogue and Episode  1 of Digimon Universe: Appli Monsters, "The Search Result is Haru Shinkai! Gatchmon Appears!"

The six-part Digimon Adventure tri movie series is said to be set in 2005, with the final film, Digimon Adventure: Last Evolution-Kizuna set in 2010.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not. Digimon (not Appmon) in Appmon are explicitly fictional, though an Agumon leaves its video game at one point. Additionally, the Adventure epilogue shows a world where everyone has Digimon, but in Appmon it's a world much like our own.

(Another note: That 'in the year 2045' thing at the beginning of each episode is quoting a certain AI researcher, not establishing the setting. Appmon is implied to be set in 2016.)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I hadn't seen anything of this particular show and am currently trying to catch up on all of the various anime